# Hibernate/JPA, get entity-object from XML

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa

Let's I have some Entity

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable 
{

   @Id
   private long id;

   @Column  
   private String code;
//...   
}
```

And I want write UnitTest for logic which use this Entity.
Can I get data from some XMLs? (without connction to database)
I want write some XMLs, ctreate in UnitTest EntityManager that is using XMLs instead of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/components.html#FlatXmlDataSet)